# iOS 5 Json Serialization

Tags: ios, json

I have used JSON Serialization to get json response, here i'mn getting all fine, but when i need to post some values as key value pair with the URL. I have done like this, but didn't get the result.

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"uname", @"pwd", @"req",nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ann", @"ann", @"login", nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:keys forKeys:objects];


if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict]) {
    NSError *error;

    result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    if (error == nil && result != nil) {
       // NSLog(@"Success");
    }
}

NSURL * url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL_address_VALUE/index.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[result length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:result];

NSURLResponse *res = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *ans = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&res error:&error];

if (error == nil) {

    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:ans encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",strData);
}
```

I don't know what goes wrong here... Please dudes help me..

Comment: You don't indicate whether any of the error checks caught anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple Errors in your Code, Use my Code as a Reference and compare it to yours and you'll get the Errors done by you.
The Below code is working correctly from the Point of View of Objective-C. There are some Errors regarding your URL or Service Side.

**Working Code :**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ann",@"uname",@"ann",@"pwd",@"login",@"req", nil];
NSLog(@"dict :: %@",dict);
NSError *error2;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:&error2];
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSLog(@"postLength :: %@",postLength);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://exemplarr-itsolutions.com/dbook/index.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error3;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error3];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:POSTReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str :: %@",str);
```

Comment: NSLog didn't display anything @Vin

Comment: @HarishSaran: Use the Code given by me.

Comment: I changed the URL, BUT NOT WORKING

Comment: this is the o/p:  2013-06-11 19:19:35.545 JSON5[24317:15d03] str ::

Comment: @HarishSaran: What's your expected o/p ?

Comment: {"status":"success","session_id":"g7fa5ltntd1gvanfjgschuccn3"}  this is i'm getting when i use the below SBJson parse method, i need to implement same in JSON Serialization

Comment: @HarishSaran : Can you give me that URL ?

Comment: u der...? did u see my link

Comment: @HarishSaran : Check my Update.It is working correctly from the Point of View of Objective-C. There are some Errors regarding your URL or Service Side.

Comment: IT IS THE OUTPUT WITH SOME XML follwing this....{"status":"success","displayName":"Ann","url":"http:\/\/exemplarr-itsolutions.com\/dbook\/temp\/b4aq3gfutjsuc8jlmus13i9nl4.xml","time":"Jun 2013, Tue 08:06:25","session_id":"b4aq3gfutjsuc8jlmus13i9nl4"}