# JSON GET and POST

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I am learning iOS app development.
I have `JSON` data coming from one of the sites in the form of `Dictionary` within an `Array` and within that `Dictionary` I have another `Array` and that contains another `Dictionary`.
for ex ,

Now I want to deserialize it and use it in my iOS app and also I have to post some data like a comment back to the server.The comment by teacher will be a POST to the server.

I hope the question makes sense.

I am stuck on how to deserialize this and use `POST` to server.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045072/ios-5-json-serialization

Comment: if u need the both methods (GET and POST)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of parts to your question:

1) To get the JSON data into a format which can easily be manipulated by your program, it's easiest to take an existing open-source JSON parser library and integrate it into your app.  I like [SBJSON](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/).  If you go to that site, it has instructions on including and using the library in your project.

2) To post a reply to the server, you need to know what format it expects the data in.  Is your app interacting with an existing website (where a user could go to a page and fill out a form), or is it talking to an API?

Comment: +1 For the JSON tool. But I'd prefer plist to JSON if I had the choice. I always want to make my app rely on less 3rd party library as possible.

Comment: Isn't apple's JSONserialization the best tool?? I read somewhere that it does the job perfectly. @arkaaito user will fill in data and send it to a site.

Comment: @Anup_B Yes, you can use NSJSONSerialization if you're targeting iOS 5+.  It may be more convenient since you're getting your JSON as response data from a web request (just use `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]`).  Can you clarify "fill in data and send it to a site"?  Is the app going to be standing in for a web browser?  If so I'll update my answer with some additional details.

Comment: @Arkaaito Yes I am planning to make it stand in for a site for the moment until I get a hang of development