# ios sending a POST request with a POST parameter

Tags: ios, post, parameters, request

I have written an iOS app and it is successfully uploading a string to a server via a POST.

```
bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text1=%@&submit1=+Absenden+", contentString];

request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.xxx /xxx/get.jsp"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I need to change the server so I used the same code, but it doesn't work, although I do get a 200 status code. The person responsible for the new server says it doesn't work because I am sending a POST but I am not sending the string as a POST parameter.

Unfortunately she doesn't know iOS so can't explain me how to do it. I have searched around, but I don't find anything and still don't understand : What does it mean to send a POST AND at the same time send a string as a POST parameter ?

Any help would be very kind.

Comment: use this link it very hopeful for you, the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715367/json-get-and-post/20715428#20715428

Comment: Thank you. I had a look, I cannot send synchronous, I need asynchronous but what I really need to understand is how to send a string as a POST parameter. Do you know what that means ?

Comment: post paramater means set the variable as the form method means look like set with the body

Comment: why you are putting + sign in your bodyString?

Comment: Ashu, because I am uploading into a form and there is button to click. It does all that @"text1=%@&submit1=+Absenden+

Comment: Anbu, thanks it's getting a bit clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle your result data with help of NSURLConnection delegate methods

```
  NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postBody=%@",@"Raja"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/promos/index.php"]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){
        // indicator.hidden = NO;
        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
```

your PHP code

```
<?php
    $result = $_POST['postBody'];


    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: iDev -Very helpful answer, thanks. The PHP part is helpful too as I could compare with my server. I believe I am very close now but I have 1 question :
In your PHP you expect 'postBody'. In my PHP I expect 'string' so I have replaced it in my code. In your example,  @"postBody=%@",@"Raja" you use a @"xx". My string is a concatenation of several strings, changing with each user, so I can't put the content of it in postBody. I tried @"postBody=%@",myString but it didn't work. What do you advise please ?

Comment: what is your myString value. do you check it null or not @user3227325

Comment: what is  response coming from server

Comment: iDev. This is the string I was trying to send this morning : test@gmail.com--2014-01-23--11:52--en--Morgen--11:51--3--3--10--0-0--04:10--0-0-0-0--0--   I do check and my Xcode console shows me the string sent, shows me a code status200 and my app displays the normal "thanks, data sent" but it doesn't arrive

Comment: iDev this is part of the php  <?php
/**
 * custom
 *
 

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo'); // List of supported time zones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

require 'class.api.php';
require 'class.config.php';
require 'class.db.php';
require 'functions.php';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (empty($_POST['string'])) {
  die('No data submitted');
}   and I get "no data submitted" from the server

Comment: iDev Server says no data submitted

Comment: accepted my answer that means click tick mark on my answer. i will tell you after some research

Comment: do you using mysql or mysqli version

Comment: what try in your php and what you expect from the response

Comment: The string is supposed to arrive and then be forwarded to another server. I expect a string and if it goes wrong I get "No data submitted"    if (empty($_POST['string'])) {
  die('No data submitted');}    I think the problem comes from  @"postBody=%@",@"Raja" . Mine is  @"postBody=%@",stringContent   and it is wrong How can I give the name of my string instead of what is inside

Comment: tell me your string content inside double eg: "your string content". because above your answer i don't which line to start and end your string content

Comment: This is my string content : "test@gmail.com--2014-01-23--11:52--en--Morgen--11:51--3--3--10--0-0--04:10--0-0-‌​0-0--0--"

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. 1-how to do it and 2- how it can help me. Also I don't know PHP on the other link :-(

Comment: But in the example code you wrote, aren't we already encoding here:   NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; ?

Comment: i don't sure but try this test@gmail.com%2D%2D2014%2D01%2D23%2D11%3A52 etc., similar

Comment: How would you concatenate multiple parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

I always use AFNetworking for any networking tasks. It will not only speed up your development, but it will also take care of many painstaking networking tasks. It is widely used framework by developers.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

and this is how you can send a post request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

You can catch the response or error in their respective blocks very easily.