# POST NSDictionary or NSArray into JSON?

Tags: ios, json

How to POST NSArray or NSDictionary values to JSON.Its possible or not.Now i have done convert NSDictionary values and NSArray values into JSON.But I am connecting with PHP my php code having encode and decode method with out encode and decode how can get my response from JSON? and How can get the values from that response?

I have tried to convert JSON format following codes::

```
 // Empty array
    NSArray *emptyArray = @[];

    // Single element array
    NSArray *singleElementArray = @[@"Error Message"];

    // Array of strings
    NSArray *arrayOfStrings = @[@"First Name", @"Last Name"];

    // Array of above arrays
    NSArray *arrayOfObjects = @[emptyArray, singleElementArray, arrayOfStrings];

    // Dictionary with several kay/value pairs and the above array of arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"BlogName" : @"iOS Developer Tips",
                           @"BlogDomain" : @"iOSDeveloperTips.com",
                           @"Array" : arrayOfObjects};

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *json;

    // Dictionary convertable to JSON ?
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
    {
        // Serialize the dictionary
        json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

        NSLog(@"json: %@", json);


        // If no errors, let's view the JSON
        if (json != nil && error == nil)
        {
          NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

          NSLog(@"JSON conversion: %@", jsonString);


        }
    }
```

I got Correct values from jsonString .I have post this string to JSON POST method its working fine but i need to NSDictionary or NSArray are post to JSON.HOW?

Comment: You need to show what is in your NSArray and what you want the JSON to look like.  There are too many answers for a vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solutions::

//[iOS 5 Json Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045072/ios-5-json-serialization)

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1",@"username",@"value2",@"password", nil];
NSLog(@"dict :: %@",dict);// What ever  parametere you want send value and key pair in this dictionary.
NSError *error2;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:&error2];
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSLog(@"postLength :: %@",postLength);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/"]];// URL post URl change here.
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error3;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error3];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:POSTReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str :: %@",str);

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&error3];

NSLog(@"parsedvalue%@",json);
```