# Remove extra spaces and new lines from JSON

Tags: ios, json, xcode

Below is my code, and am trying to parse a JSON; I am getting response but when am printing dictionary, it's null.

below is the response string, result of JSON.

```
 NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jobid=%@",idjob];
 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;
 NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"login:%@",str);

 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

 NSLog(@"aarraa:%@",jsonDict);
```

Response for str :

```
  {"Jobdesc":[{"jobid":"11260","job_title":"Linux + Nagios System Administrator","job_desc":"&lt;p&gt;Technical skills required:&lt;/p&gt;

   &lt;ol&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Should be ready to work during French timings&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Linux Certification / training is a must&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Linux System administration (Red hat Linux, CentOS Servers)&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Experience in LAMP configuration and troubleshooting&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Knowledge on windows OS&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Experience on monitoring tools like Nagios / Centreon,    Ops5&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;Scripting in Shell, Perl or Python&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;/ol&gt;
","job_role":"Linux + Nagios System Administrator","job_exp":"1-5 year","job_education":"Others","job_location":"Delhi","job_address":"Delhi","job_company_name":"Pandya Business Solutions.","job_company_url":"http://www.pandyabusinesssolutions.com/","job_company_email":"singhjapesh@gmail.com","job_status":""}]}
```

but parameter jsonDict is null.

Comment: What does `[error localizedDescription]` say?

Comment: @ozgur do i need to add it to my code ?

Comment: Yes you need to do: `NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);`

Comment: Can you log error and post here whatever it is
NSLog(@"error:%@",error);

Comment: @ozgur Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 136." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 136.}

Comment: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. @SatishMavani

Comment: try `NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];`

Comment: Try my code 100% working..

Comment: Maybe with `NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];` since you used that encoding for the post data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried validating JSON response, and found that there were extra spaces in JSON so below is my resolved answer.

```
  NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jobid=%@",idjob];
  NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ncrjobs.in/webservice/jobdesc.php"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;
 NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSCharacterSet *spaces=[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
 NSPredicate *predicates=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF !=''"];
 NSArray *temparray=[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:spaces]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicates];
 str=[temparray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
 NSString  *string = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\r\n]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: @seggy yup ! thanks to all of you. for your help. :)

Comment: I would blame the creator of the web service to send better JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize data like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: What are  you using to post data is it  AFNetworking or ASIHttpRequest ?

Comment: Just check This link this might help You..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410762/post-nsdictionary-or-nsarray-into-json

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL"];

NSURL *nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonString];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:nurl];
NSError *error = nil;


NSDictionary *dictResult = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: @Shikha its working perfectly on my project please check your web service..

Comment: can you please show me your full code,because am posting parameters too.

Comment: @Shikha you need this code only i get data from this code too....if possible please send me your web service i will give you result from this.

Comment: parameter to be passed is : jobbed you can send it's value as 12281

Comment: @Shikha if this is not urgent please wait because i m busy with my work.

Comment: please remove web services @Shikha

Comment: yeah sure , tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to serialise your data just before you completely get it, below is the code with completionHandler which will begin further process once you get all your data, so try this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: theRequest queue [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

            NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }];
```